# undefined reference to gzdopen, gzclose, gzread

Tags: zlib, libxml2, undefined-reference

I have compiled and installed the 2.2.7.2 version of libxml. While compiling, I have this error: Makefile:755: recipe for target 'install-data-local' failed. But the lib files are correctly generated (libxml2.a and libxml2.so). 
I'd like to use libxml2 in a C project so I edited my makefiles in order to integrate lib files (libxml2.a and libxml2.so).
The problem is that when I compile my project I get the followings errors:
/libxml2.a(xmlIO.o): In function `xmlGzfileRead': undefined reference to`gzdopen'
/libxml2.a(xmlIO.o): In function `xmlGzfileRead': undefined reference to`gzclose'
/libxml2.a(xmlIO.o): In function `xmlGzfileRead': undefined reference to`gzread'
...etc
It seems that I have to install the zlib library in order to resolve this linker errors. I installed the zlib library and edited the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in order to add the path where are the zlib libraries. 
I recompiled my project, but I still always having the same linker errors.

Would you please help me to resolve those linker errors.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

See the [libxml2 FAQ](http://www.xmlsoft.org/FAQ.html#Developer):

> *Troubles compiling or linking programs using libxml2*
>
> Usually the problem comes from the fact that the compiler doesn't get the right compilation or linking flags. There is a small shell script xml2-config which is installed as part of libxml2 usual install process which provides those flags. Use
>
> ```
> xml2-config --cflags
> ```
>
> to get the compilation flags and
>
> ```
> xml2-config --libs
> ```
>
> to get the linker flags. Usually this is done directly from the Makefile as:
>
> ```
> CFLAGS=`xml2-config --cflags`
>
> LIBS=`xml2-config --libs`
> ```

On my current system, the output from `xml2-config --libs` is

```
-lxml2 -lz -lpthread -licucore -lm
```

Comment: hello, I opened the file xml2_config, the prefix is /home/libs/libxml2, and it is the repository where my lib files are generated. But, when I execute the command xml2-config --cflags, I get -I/usr/include/libxml2 instead of -I/home/libs/libxml2 is that normal?  Also, when I execute the command xml2-config --libs I get just -lxml2   What is wrong?

Comment: @ZINEBA Are you sure you're not executing the system-wide version of `xml2-config` (typically in `/usr/bin`)? If your prefix is `/home/libs/libxml2`, you have to run `/home/libs/libxml2/bin/xml2-config`. Also, version 2.7.2 is over eight years old. Try a newer version, or add `-lz` manually.

Comment: hello Yes you are right when I set the command xml2-config --libs without specifying the link of the file, by default the system execute the /usr/bin/linxml2-config file, but right now, I specify the hole link /home/libs/libxml2/bin/xml2-config --cflags and I get the rignt repo: -I/home/libs/libxml2/include/libxml2 I have installed a newer version of libxml2 ( the 2.9.3 version ), now xml2-config --libs gives -lxm2 -lz -lm -ldl. I compiled my source code I get always the same errors as above and I get moreover the followings error: undefined reference to `lzma_code' `lzma_properties_decode'...

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by the full link command. I note that I try to add the libxml2 to a large project where do we have many makefiles and config files. 
So, for your response I don't know where do I have to add CFLAGS=`xml2-config --cflags`
LIBS=`xml2-config --libs`