# Undefined reference to symbol 'gzclose' error when getting library - go

Tags: go, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation

When I try to get one of my libraries on my linux machine with the following command:

```
go get -t github.com/bakape/thumbnailer
```

then I get this error message:

> -# github.com/bakape/thumbnailer /usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-blob.o): undefined reference to symbol 'gzclose'
>   //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

People who encountered this error said this is a linking error and they fixed it by adding some additional tags in the Makefile. I did this too, but this did not work for me. I tried so many solutions, but nothing seems to work for me.

I'm using the following library:
https://github.com/bakape/thumbnailer

This is the Makefile:

```
clean:
    rm -f testdata/*_thumb.*
```

The creator mentioned undocumented zlib dependencies. All of them are installed:

```
zlib1g is already the newest version (1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1).
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1).
```

-

```
ubuntu@root:~$ ls -F -sh /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.*
   0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1@  104K /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
```

Here is the full installation process:

```
 ubuntu@root:~$ go get -u -v -x github.com/bakape/thumbnailer
    cd /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer
    git config remote.origin.url
    github.com/bakape/thumbnailer (download)
    cd /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer
    git pull --ff-only
    cd /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer
    git submodule update --init --recursive
    cd /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer
    git show-ref
    cd /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer
    git submodule update --init --recursive
    WORK=/tmp/go-build312713059
    github.com/bakape/thumbnailer
    mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/
    mkdir -p $WORK/github.com/bakape/
    cd /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer
    pkg-config --cflags libavcodec libavutil libavformat GraphicsMagick++ libavcodec libavutil libavformat libswscale
    pkg-config --libs libavcodec libavutil libavformat GraphicsMagick++ libavcodec libavutil libavformat libswscale
    CGO_LDFLAGS="-g" "-O2" "-lm" "-L/usr/local/lib" "-lGraphicsMagick++" "-lGraphicsMagick" "-lavcodec" "-lavutil" "-lavformat" "-lswscale" /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/cgo -objdir $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ -importpath github.com/bakape/thumbnailer -- -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 audio.go buf.go build_flags_gpl.go ffmpeg.go meta.go thumbnailer.go video.go
    cd $WORK
    gcc -fdebug-prefix-map=a=b -c trivial.c
    gcc -gno-record-gcc-switches -c trivial.c
    cd $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj
    gcc -I /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I ./ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o ./_cgo_export.o -c _cgo_export.c
    gcc -I /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I ./ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o ./audio.cgo2.o -c audio.cgo2.c
    gcc -I /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I ./ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o ./buf.cgo2.o -c buf.cgo2.c
    gcc -I /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I ./ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o ./build_flags_gpl.cgo2.o -c build_flags_gpl.cgo2.c
    gcc -I /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I ./ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o ./ffmpeg.cgo2.o -c ffmpeg.cgo2.c
    gcc -I /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I ./ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o ./meta.cgo2.o -c meta.cgo2.c
    gcc -I /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I ./ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o ./thumbnailer.cgo2.o -c thumbnailer.cgo2.c
    gcc -I /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I ./ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o ./video.cgo2.o -c video.cgo2.c
    cd /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer
    gcc -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/audio.o -c audio.c
    gcc -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ffmpeg.o -c ffmpeg.c
    gcc -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/init.o -c init.c
    gcc -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/meta.o -c meta.c
    gcc -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/video.o -c video.c
    g++ -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/lodepng -std=c++17 -O3 -o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/compress_png.cc.o -c compress_png.cc
    g++ -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/lodepng -std=c++17 -O3 -o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/thumbnailer.cc.o -c thumbnailer.cc
    g++ -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/lodepng -std=c++17 -O3 -o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/util.cc.o -c util.cc
    cd $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj
    gcc -I /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -I/usr/local/include/GraphicsMagick -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I ./ -g -O2 -I/home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/libimagequant -std=c11 -std=c11 -O3 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE -std=c11 -o ./_cgo_main.o -c _cgo_main.c
    cd /home/ubuntu/go/src/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer
    g++ -I . -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=$WORK=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/_cgo_.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/_cgo_main.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/_cgo_export.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/audio.cgo2.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/buf.cgo2.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/build_flags_gpl.cgo2.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ffmpeg.cgo2.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/meta.cgo2.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/thumbnailer.cgo2.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/video.cgo2.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/audio.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/ffmpeg.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/init.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/meta.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/video.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/compress_png.cc.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/thumbnailer.cc.o $WORK/github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/_obj/util.cc.o -g -O2 -lm -L/usr/local/lib -lGraphicsMagick++ -lGraphicsMagick -lavcodec -lavutil -lavformat -lswscale
    # github.com/bakape/thumbnailer
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-blob.o): undefined reference to symbol 'gzclose'
    //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603178/undefined-reference-to-symbol-gzclose-with-cmake-and-opencv ? Or rather https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700414/compilation-problems-with-zlib or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259441/undefined-reference-to-gzopen-in-moses or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898192/undefined-reference-to-gzdopen-gzclose-gzread

Comment: "People who encountered this error said this is a linking error and they fixed it by adding: x. I tried this too but this did not work for me"

Comment: What these postings seem to say is that it is a link order issue, the order of the libraries specified. And they mention `-lz` and not `-lm`. And since there appears to be an issue with your `makefile`, do you think it would be a good idea to include a copy of your `makefile` in your posting?or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149515/undefined-reference-to-gzopen-etc

Comment: I have provided you a list of stackoverflow postings of this exact same issue and they all seem to agree on what is to be done. I have also asked for a copy of your `makefile` to be added to your posting. Finally this issue, at the bottom, indicates there may be an undocumented dependency on the zlib dev package https://github.com/bakape/thumbnailer/issues/26

Comment: Yes, I know, the newest version of zlib is already installed. I added the Makefile to the initial question. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You built a local static GraphicsMagick and you did not configure it properly. The best thing for you is to remove the current GraphicsMagick by using the command:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

in the GraphicsMagick folder.

After that, simply install GraphicsMagick using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
```

All library links will be handled automatically by the Advanced Packaging Tool.